# Use BPReplay (font) in iOS app

Tags: ios, fonts

I want to use the font BPReplay for my iOS app. How can I add it and does it work?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following.

1. Add a property `Fonts provided by application` in your APPNAME_info.plist
   Add items under it and put the name of your font against each item as shown in the picture
   [image]
2. Use the font in your app like this

   UIFont *yourFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Century" size:28];

   [SomeLabel setFont:yourFont];

Hope this helps

Comment: Heyho, thanks first of all. so don't I have to add any font-files? because the font is not listed in the "custom"-list in the details-section in the storyboard. And I guess I can't do that with storyboards right?